# Html and css layout issue

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a (fairly) basic layout with two panes floated to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/enqXe/14/
However, the top one isn't taking up 60% and the bottom one 40%. Part of the problem I think is that #rightPaneHolder isn't 100% of the height for some reason. Is this some simple css error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
body,html{height:100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/enqXe/15/